Endomorphisms over direct sum of irreducible representations equal to direct sum of endomorphisms over irreducible representations
So for a group G according to Maschke's theorem we know $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{d} V_i^{d_i}$ where V is the regular representation, $V_i$ are distinct irreducible representations. We also know. $d_i=dim(V_i)$. I want to show $end(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{d} V_i^{d_i})=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{d} end(V_i)^{d_i}$. We can use Schur's lemma to show that that any element of $end(V_i)$ is a scalar multiple of the identity and therefore $\mathbb{C} $ is isomorphic to $end(V_i)$. In my mind when I'm thinking of this in terms of matrices the right hand side would be the $c\times c$ ($c:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{d}d^2)$ matrices with all but the diagonal elements zero. However, can't we also have endomoprhisms  on $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{d} V_i^{d_i}$ where the matrix equivalent has non-zero elements outside of the diagonal? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here. What am I missing here and why does the above equality hold?

Schur also tells you that the only morphism between "distinct" (i.e. non-isomorphic) irreducible representations is $0$.

Schur's lemma tells us that for two irreducible unitary representations $(\pi, V_\pi)$ and $(\tau, V_\tau)$ we have $\dim \text{Hom}_G(V_\pi, V_\tau) = 1$ iff $\pi\cong \tau$ as representations and $\dim\text{Hom}_G(V_\pi, V_\tau) = 0$ otherwise; this forbids us to get off-diagonal elements. Here $\text{Hom}_G(V_\pi, V_\tau)$ denotes $G$-equivariant [i.e. $T\circ\pi(g)=\tau(g)\circ T$] linear homomorphisms.

As commented 8 min ago:

Schur also tells you that the only morphism between two "distinct" (i.e. non-isomorphic) irreducible representations is $0$.


yeah sorry about that... i was already typing the answer before you posted the comment and only read it afterwards...
